# Unix separate multiple commands which has '&' (execute in background) in the end

Tags: linux, unix, bash, shell, shell-scripting

To separate regular commands in Unix is to put semicolon in the end like this:

```
cd /path/to/file;./someExecutable;
```

But it seems not working for commands like this:

```
./myProgram1 > /dev/null &
./myProgram2 > /dev/null &
=>./myProgram1 > /dev/null &;./myProgram2 > /dev/null &;
```

Is there any way separate these kind of commands?

Also, if are below 2 cases are equivalent if I copy paste to command prompt? Thanks.

```
cd /path/to/file;./someExecutable;

cd /path/to/file;
./someExecutable;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well the ";" makes the shell wait for the command to finish and then continues with the next command.

The "&" will send any process directly into the background and continues with the next command - no matter if the first command finished or is still running.

So "&;" will not work like you expect.

But actually I'm unsure what you expect.

Try this in your shell:

```
sleep 2 && echo 1 & echo 2 & sleep 3 && echo 3
```

it will output:
    2
    1
    3

Now compare it with

```
sleep 2 ; echo 1 & echo 2 & sleep 3 ; echo 3
```

which will output
    1
    2
    3

Regards.

Comment: So if I want run 2 commands at the same time in the background. It should be     ./myProgram1 > /dev/null & ./myProgram1 > /dev/null &   right?

Comment: Yes. But actually it's not EXACTLY happening in the same nano-second :P

Answer (score 14):

`command1 & command2`  Will execute `command1`, send the process to the background, and immediately begin executing `command2`, even if `command1` has not completed.

`command1 ; command2` Will execute `command1` and then execute `command2` once `command1` finishes, regardless of whether `command1` exited successfully.

`command1 && command2` will only execute `command2` once `command1` has completed execution successfully.  If `command1` fails, `command2` will not execute.

(...also, for completeness...)

`command1 || command2` will only execute `command2` if `command1` fails (exits with a non-zero exit code.)

Comment: No problem.  Hope it helps!  Though I'm not sure if it actually answers your original question.